# Rules for slang of Japanese numbers

Tags: slang, numbers, puns

I often hear Japanese using a different method for saying a number like "248" as によんぱ — especially for highways and license plates.

While this one is easy to understand, there are others that I don't quite understand.
Could someone provide a list of the different pronunciations of each number?

"2525" being ニコニコ is probably a good example of what I'm talking about.

> 1:い
>   2:に
>   3:
>   4:よん
>   5:こ
>   6:
>   7:
>   8:は、ぱ
>   9:

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​4649

Comment: Used a lot in phone numbers too. Sometimes you're allowed to choose the last 4 digits of a new number, but 8686 (はろはろ) is always gone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's called [語呂合わせ]{ごろあわせ}; see the full article [on Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AA%9E%E5%91%82%E5%90%88%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9B).

Quoting [from there](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AA%9E%E5%91%82%E5%90%88%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9B#.E6.95.B0.E5.AD.97.E3.81.AE.E6.9A.97.E8.A8.98):

> 1 : いち、い、ひとつ、ひと
>
> 2 : に、ふたつ、ふた、ふ、つ（英語から）、じ
>
> 3 : さん、さ、みっつ、みつ、み
>
> 4 : よん、よ、よっつ、し、ふぉ（英語から）、ほ
>
> 5 : ご、こ、い、いつつ、いつ
>
> 6 : ろく、ろ、むっつ、むつ、む
>
> 7 : しち、ななつ、なな、な
>
> 8 : はち、は、ぱあ、やっつ、やつ、や、やあ
>
> 9 : きゅう、きゅ、く、ここのつ、ここの、こ
>
> 0 :
> れい、れ、ぜろ、ない、わ（字形から）、まる（字形から）、おー（アルファベットのOから。）

Comment: hmm, they forgot the simple パ...

Comment: The corresponding English-language article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_wordplay

Answer (score 7):

There is no rule per se and an exhaustive list will need to be in a form of community wiki to be editable by everyone.

A mix of "on-" and "kun-" readings (without the last consonant) + some English pronunciation + some kana modification will work.

I'll list what I've heard with some example if possible: (I'm sure there are some commercial playing on these to advertise their phone numbers as well as a lot of other puns with numbers)

> 0: オ (0840 = おはよう), レイ, マル
>   1: ィ (0141 = おいしい)
>   2: ツ, 二
>   3: サン　（～さん）, サ, ミ
>   4: シ, ヨ　(4649 = よろしく)
>   5: ゴ, ィ
>   6: ロ　(168 = いろは), ム　(361 = さむい)
>   7: ナ　(723 = なつみ)
>   8: パ　(883 = パパさん), ハ
>   9: ク (931 = くさい)
>   10: ト, トウ, テン

Answer (score 4):

As with @repecmps's answer, there's no real set rule, but often businesses will make up catchy words so that you can easily remember them.  For example, the phone number 0840-0141 could be おはよう、おいしい to remind you of a breakfast diner.  Also, people with the last name Saito (さいとう) often attach 3110 (3-さ, 1-い, 10-とう) to their email address, screen names, etc.  You just have to be clever.