# What are the ゴロ番, and how do they work?

Tags: numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rules for slang of Japanese numbers](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/853/rules-for-slang-of-japanese-numbers)

They seem to be some form of replacing kana sounds with numbers to spell things with numbers. Are these actually used anywhere "real"? or are they just a bit of fansite silliness?

Comment: there is a big wikipedia page on them. i've seen my friends use them i think they're a ton of fun