# Why the mixture of *on* and *kun* readings of numbers?

Tags: readings, numbers, puns

One thing that always puzzled me was why some terms and names that are based on numbers will mix the *on* and *kun* readings. I never really understood the rules for that, but it occurs to me that there must be some.

For example, the word *yakuza* is derived from 8-9-3, a no-score hand in the 花札 (*hanafuda*) card game. This comprises:

> や  — 8, *ya(ttsu)*, a *kun* reading
>   く  — 9, *ku*, an *on* reading
>   ざ  — 3, *za* (for *san*), an *on* reading

Similarly, the famous Admiral Yamamoto had a given name of Isoroku (meaning, curiously, "56"), which mixed *kun* readings (or their variants) for 5 and 10 plus the *on* reading for 6.

I just want to know how to make sense of this — or if it is even necessary that it make sense. Perhaps it is simply a matter of putting together sounds that the originator(s) of the term found pleasing?

**Edit**: I want to add that the usages sometimes seem capricious to me, as when you hear 二人（ふたり）to refer to two people but 二人前（ににんまえ）to refer to a restaurant serving for two people or the task that two people have before them, although you can hear ふたりまえ there as well.

Comment: That's a very interesting question, but I think it's along the same lines as why some words in English have both Greek and Latin roots..."television" is the most well known one I think, but it actually happens a lot, especially with new words ^.^
I found a neat link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word for those curious :)

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/853/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually an interesting topic, here's a quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word#Japanese):

> In Japanese, hybrid words are common in kango – words formed from
>   kanji characters – where some of the characters may be pronounced
>   using Chinese pronunciations (on'yomi, from Chinese morphemes), and
>   others in the same word are pronounced using Japanese pronunciations
>   (kun'yomi, from Japanese morphemes). These are known as jūbako (重箱) or
>   yutō (湯桶) words, which are themselves examples of this kind of
>   compound (they are autological words): the first character of jūbako
>   is read using on'yomi, the second kun'yomi, while it is the other way
>   around with yutō. Other examples include 場所 basho "place" (kun-on), 金色
>   kin'iro "golden" (on-kun) and 合気道 aikidō "the martial art Aikido"
>   (kun-on-on).

For more in-depth reading into the topic, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Japanese_vocabulary).